# IOS subscriptions stuck in Waiting for Review for ever

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, subscription, review

I submitted my first built with subscriptions. The built got approved 2 weeks ago, the subscriptions are still waiting for review. For some reason the subscription review process seems to be a different team / timeline.

Apple has been fairly fast with built reviews in my experience (1-2 business days). But reviewing my subscriptions which should be really simple (just a price list?) is now stuck for 2 weeks already in Waiting for review.

This is a major problem since my app is live, and offers upgrade buttons e.t.c. Users are super confused by having these buttons but not seeing any plans to upgrade to.

Is this normal? I tried to reach out multiple times via contact forms but no response yet.

Comment: DId this ever get resolved? I am having the same issue with auto-renewing subscriptions.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I removed everything from review and went through it again. It was stuck for three weeks. I send about 10 emails to different departments, nothing worked. Submitting everything fresh again worked. In the meanwhile got bunch of negative reviews since they approved the app but not the subscriptions, so had a malfunctioning app for a while.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Apple's behavior, especially with regard to the app store and review, is not a programming matter.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal (but definitely not ideal, but again we're dealing with the Apple so nothing is ideal). Anyone watching this question should ensure to write code in such a way that the app is usable without the subscription and show the upgrade buttons on the UI only when the products are available from the StoreKit framework.

If required, go to extreme of making the app paid and letting users access content inside the app until the subscription is approved.